# Android emulator for windows mobile?

Tags: windows, android-emulator

Could python or another piece of programming Integrate or work with google play or apk files to work with windows mobile (please be kind I'm not tech savy) my question comes from being and android user and I've switched toa Lumia 650 (windows based) ....and it is lacking in ALL media and entertainment realms....

Answer (score 0):

You should install a driver Go through the below article you will find an appropriate driver to your device

[1] : https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html?utm_source=udacity&utm_medium=course&utm_campaign=android_basics